# Gridview Rows Items Misalignment to Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, performance, gridview

Please see image first

[image]

[image]

Misaligning of row items to header happens after **keypress event** in textbox for record searching takes place. It works using javascript using this code

```
var $KeyPressSearch = jQuery.noConflict();
function filter2(phrase, _id) {

    var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var table = document.getElementById(_id);

    var ele;
    for (var r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
        ele = table.rows[r].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
        var displayStyle = 'none';
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i]) >= 0)
                displayStyle = '';
            else {
                displayStyle = 'none';
                break;
            }
        }
        table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;

    }

    var lblTotalDSRdata = $KeyPressSearch("#grd tr").length;
}
```

this only happens to gridviews with jquery injected codes used to fixate the header. to other gridviews that do not use, all works fine.

So to fix the gridview header I apply the tutorial from this link http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/  **(Basic)**

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Have you fixed the width of any column in your Gridview ?

Comment: No. I have not put any fixed width value to any of the columns @Shaiwal